# land of lisp src webserver.lisp

Tags: webdev.webserver, usocket, land-of-lisp

while I was learning in "land of lisp" chapter 12 and 13 about "socket".
I use lispbox, so I need install a socket.At last, I found **usocket** available.
this is  a sample about how to use **usocket**, to bulid a webserver.

```
(defun serve (request-handler)
  "serve as a web server,used to handle request 
   like 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/greeting'"
 (let ((socket (usocket:socket-listen "0.0.0.0" 8080 :reuse-address t)))
 (unwind-protect
   (loop (with-open-stream (stream 
                            (usocket:socket-stream 
                                      (usocket:socket-accept socket)))
            (let* ((url    (parse-url (read-line stream)))
                    (path   (car url))
                    (header (get-header stream))
                    (params (append (cdr url) 
                                    (get-content-params stream header)))
                    (*standard-output* stream))
               (funcall request-handler path header params))))
   (usocket:socket-close socket))))
```

the origin ‘serve’ function in http://landoflisp.com/webserver.lisp

```
(defun serve (request-handler)
 (let ((socket (socket-server 8080)))
 (unwind-protect
   (loop (with-open-stream (stream (socket-accept socket))
             (let* ((url    (parse-url (read-line stream)))
                    (path   (car url))
                    (header (get-header stream))
                    (params (append (cdr url) 
                                    (get-content-params stream header)))
                    (*standard-output* stream))
               (funcall request-handler path header params))))
   (socket-server-close socket))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## API definition

- usocket (class)
- stream-usocket (class; usocket derivative)
- stream-server-usocket (class; usocket derivative)
- socket-connect (function) [ to create an active/connected socket ]
  socket-connect host port &key element-type
    where `host' is a vectorized ip
                    or a string representation of a dotted ip address
                    or a hostname for lookup in the DNS system
- socket-listen (function) [ to create a passive/listening socket ]
   socket-listen host port &key reuseaddress backlog element-type
     where `host' has the same definition as above
- socket-accept (method) [ to create an active/connected socket ]
   socket-accept socket &key element-type
     returns (server side) a connected socket derived from a
     listening/passive socket.
- socket-close (method)
  socket-close socket
    where socket a previously returned socket
- socket (usocket slot accessor),
    the internal/implementation defined socket representation
- socket-stream (usocket slot accessor),
  socket-stream socket
    the return value of which satisfies the normal stream interface